# How to make pagination in PHP, mysql

Tags: php

I wonder how to make pagination in PHP
May I ask you a favor of you?

This code have not error.
But I do not know what $current_page make

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "dbdb") or die("error");


$page_size = 10;

$page_list_size = 10;

if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
    $valueTosearch = $_POST['valueTosearch'];

    $query = "SELECT * FROM `shipment` WHERE CONCAT(`Ship_Date`,`Model_No`,`Serial_No`)LIKE'%" . $valueTosearch . "%' ORDER BY Ship_Date DESC LIMIT $page_size";
    $search_result = filterTable($query);
} else {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `shipment` ORDER BY Ship_Date DESC LIMIT $page_size";
    $search_result = filterTable($query);
}

function filterTable($query) {
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "dbdb");
    $filter_Result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
    return $filter_Result;
}

echo "<center><h1>info</h1></center> <br><br>";

$ret = mysqli_query($con, $query);
if ($ret) {
    echo mysqli_num_rows($ret), " <br><br>";
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($ret);
} else {
    echo "error :" . mysqli_error($con);
    exit();
}


$query = "SELECT count(*) FROM shipment";
$result_count = mysqli_query($con, $query);
$result_row = mysqli_fetch_array($result_count);
$total_row = $result_row[0];


if ($total_row <= 0)
    $total_row = 0;
$total_page = ceil($total_row / $page_size);



$current_page = ceil();
?>
```

I wonder how to make pagination in PHP
May I ask you a favor of you?

This code have not error.
But I do not know what $current_page make

Comment: Please remove the duplicated paragraphs. Can you also explain in more detail what you're asking? Your question is currently unclear.

Comment: @Edwin Helpful this tutorial https://phppot.com/php/ajax-pagination-with-php/

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a mistake on the mysql query, limitting to $page_size you will get only a number of results = $page_size, but you will always get the $page-size 1st elements, if you want to page results you need to add offset.

This way first page will be $page_size elements with offset 0, second page $page_size elements with $page_size offset, and in general the nth page will be $page_size elements with (n-1) times $page_size offset.

In the last line you are missing an argument:

$current_page = ceil(); should be $current_page = ceil($lowest_element_in_result_set/$page_size);

Answer (score 1):

$current_page should be the number of the page user want to view and this would be a input from user.
this is my implementation.
hope this will help you .

```
$pagenum = $_GET['pagenum'];//get the page number user want to view
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "9272", "new_platform_7");
$query = 'select * from table1';
$filter_Result = mysqli_query($con, $query);//execute query without limit to get total number of rows
$rows = mysqli_num_rows($filter_Result);//total number of rows
if (!(isset($pagenum)))  
{  
$pagenum = 1;//if user hasn't give page number set page to page number 1
}
$page_rows = 30;//the page size (number of rows in each page)
$last = ceil($rows/$page_rows);//total number of pages //use ceil to avoid fractions
if ($pagenum < 1){  //if user give negative page number. set page number to 1
$pagenum = 1;  //this will happen if user clicked the Previous page link when current page is 1
}elseif ($pagenum > $last)  //if page number is greater than calculated number of pages . set page number to last page
{  
$pagenum = $last;  //this will happen if user clicked the next page link when current page is the last page
}
//($pagenum - 1) * $page_rows calculates where to start the lmit
$query.= ' limit ' .($pagenum - 1) * $page_rows .',' .$page_rows;//limit result 
echo $query;
$filter_Result = mysqli_query($con, $query);//execute query with limits
//pagination links
echo '<a href="?pagenum=1&">First Page</a>';
echo '<a href="?pagenum='.($pagenum-1).'&">Previous Page</a>';
echo '<a href="?pagenum='.($pagenum+1).'&">Next Page</a>';
echo '<a href="?pagenum='.$last.'&">Last Page</a>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in a simple way.

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost","roo","","dbname");
 if(!$link):
    echo "something wrong with the database connection";
 endif;

 //check to see if the page (value) is available
 if(isset($_GET['pageNo']):
    $page = $_GET['pageNo'];

 else:
    $page = "";

 endif;

 if($page == "" || $page == 1):
     $start_to_count_rowNo = 0;
 else:
 $start_to_count_rowNo = ($page * &item_displayed_per_page) -  &item_displayed_per_page;

 endif;
     //here choose how many items do you want to display per page
     &item_displayed_per_page = 10;

//Now select the data to display them
 $query = "SELECT * FROM table_name LIMIT $start_to_count_rowNo, $item_displayed_per_page";

 $readData = mysqli_query($link, $query);

//obtaining total number of data(rows) in a database
$sql = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM table_name");
$total_row = mysqli_num_rows($sql);

$pageNo = ceil($total_row / &item_displayed_per_page);

//using bootstrap add class pager in unordered list to style the list


?>

<ul class="pager">
<?php
   //display out the page # like 1,2,3 ....
for($i = 0; $i <= $pageNo; $i++){

    echo "</li><a href='pagename.php?pageNo={$i}'>{$i}</a></li>";
}

?>
</ul>
```